# piston git support?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-piston

I found piston seems a decent tool for managing rails plugins, but when I try to do piston convert for my project with git based plugins, it just went dead completely and seems its trying to look for .svn with svn tools.

I am on piston 1.4.0, is that git natively supported or I would have to build from edge?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using piston 1.9.x for exactly this reason - since 1.9, it has [supported Git importing](http://blog.teksol.info/2008/03/17/piston-1-9-0-official-preview-release.html).

Instructions on installing can be found [here](http://blog.teksol.info/2008/03/23/piston-1-9-1-import-goodness.html).

Comment: so is that mean I have to build from source?

Answer (score 0):

check out [braid](http://github.com/evilchelu/braid/tree/master).

> Simple tool to help track git and svn vendor branches in a git repository